# Compare and add in a single line of code?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, push

Given an array
`[9,5,4,2,1,1,5,8,1,1]`

is there a way to remove all the `1`s and add equal amount of `x`s at the end.
To get this
`[9,5,4,2,5,8,x,x,x,x]`

Am looking for a way to do this in one line. Curious if there is a technique here I may be missing or maybe there is none.

I am clearly wrong in my use of `this` in the below example. But gives you an idea of what I am trying to do.

```js
let test = [9,5,4,2,1,1,5,8,1,1];

console.log(test.map(el => el !== 1 ?el :this.push('x'));
```

Comment: *"Am looking for a way to do this in one line"* Why? If we know why you want to do that, we can help you better. You can do almost anything "in one line" as line breaks aren't important in JavaScript (usually), but often it hinders readability and debugging.

Comment: `map` doesn't set `this`.

Comment: AFAIK, `map()` doesn't provide any way for the function to access the result array that's being constructed.

Comment: @Barmar I understand. I only used it to explain what I intended to do. Would be great if you could return an action which it can run on itself once an array is generated.

Comment: If you want to run something on the resulting array, just pass the result to another function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `filter()` and `fill()`

```js
let test = [9, 5, 4, 2, 1, 1, 5, 8, 1, 1];

let res = test.filter(el => el !== 1)

res = res.concat(Array(test.length - res.length).fill('x'))

console.log(res);
```

Using `reduce()`

```js
let test = [9, 5, 4, 2, 1, 1, 5, 8, 1, 1];

let res = test.reduceRight((a, e) => e !== 1 ? [e, ...a] : [...a, 'x'], [])

console.log(res);
```

Comment: The OP asked for a "single line" (which I think we can reasonably interpret to mean "single statement") which while a silly restriction (IMHO) is still there...

Comment: @amars It just adds the elements at the start and end of the accumulator

Comment: btw, [`Array#reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) exists.

Answer (score 4):

You could take two loops to get the array reordered.

```js
var array = [9, 5, 4, 2, 1, 1, 5, 8, 1, 1],
    j = 0;

console.log(...array);

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] !== 1) array[j++] = array[i];
}
while (j < array.length) array[j++] = 'x';

console.log(...array);
```

Basically the same wrapped in a `forEach` callback.

```js
var array = [9, 5, 4, 2, 1, 1, 5, 8, 1, 1];

array.forEach((j => (v, i, a) => { if (i + 1 === a.length) while (j < a.length) a[j++] = 'x'; else if (v !== 1) a[j++] = v; })(0));

console.log(...array);
```

An even shorter approach with mapping of the values

```js
var array = [9, 5, 4, 2, 1, 1, 5, 8, 1, 1];

array = array.map((j => (v, _, a) => { while (a[j] === 1) j++; return j in a ? a[j++] : 'x'; })(0));

console.log(...array);
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: As is called out in the comments below, the manner in which [`.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is leveraged in this solution is a bit strange (to put it generously).  I would recommend looking to the other posted solutions for approaches that are a bit more robust.**

---

It cannot be done (or at least done easily) in one *operation/loop*, but it can be done in a single line:

```js
let test = [9,5,4,2,1,1,5,8,1,1];

let output = test.map((num) => num === 1 ? 'x' : num).sort((a,b) => b === 'x' ? -1 : 0)

console.log(output);
```

Your usage of `this` didn't make sense; in a loop operation you `return` the desired output (either explicitly or as an implicit return from a fat-arrow function).

So in the above example, we first use loop once with [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return a new array that has all the `1`s replaced with `"x"`s.  We then loop over the newly returned array to [`.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) all the instances of `"1"` to the end of the array.

Comment: This is neat. I didn't knew this use of sort function. Thanks.

Comment: i am not happy with this solution, because it uses sort which needs to be stable for unsort the other elements and the callback is not symetrically, because it uses only one element and not both and the relation between both elements.

Comment: @NinaScholz - I'm afraid I don't understand your concern.  I know that comments are not intended for discussion, but if you were able and willing to update your answer to include specifically the advantage it has over this answer I would be very interested to understand the shortcomings of my posted solution.  Thanks.

Comment: it is not the point of my answer, but it just the problem with sorting.

Comment: @NinaScholz - That's fair-- I can see where the manner in which the sorting is approached here is a bit flimsy / hacky / non-semantic / non-idiomatic, and how that could potential cause issues.

Answer (score 1):

Re your use of `this`: you can't access the array that `map` is building from within the `map` callback, it  isn't accessible to your code until `map` returns it.

Technically, you *could* do this with one expression on a single line:

```
console.log(Array.from(Object.assign(test.filter(el => el !== 1), {length: test.length})).map(el => el === undefined ? "x" : el));
```

That assumes no `undefined` entries in the original, which seems reasonable given the sample given.

Live Example:

```js
let test = [9,5,4,2,1,1,5,8,1,1];

console.log(Array.from(Object.assign(test.filter(el => el !== 1), {length: test.length})).map(el => el === undefined ? "x" : el));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

**But**, I'd strongly advise against it. I'd just do it the simple way:

```
const result = test.filter(el => el !== 1);
while (result.length < test.length) {
    result.push("x");
}
```

Live Example:

```js
let test = [9,5,4,2,1,1,5,8,1,1];

const result = test.filter(el => el !== 1);
while (result.length < test.length) {
    result.push("x");
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Or perhaps

```
const result = test.filter(el => el !== 1);
result.push(...Array(test.length - result.length).fill("x"));
```

Live Example:

```js
let test = [9,5,4,2,1,1,5,8,1,1];

const result = test.filter(el => el !== 1);
result.push(...Array(test.length - result.length).fill("x"));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

...but for me even that is a bit overcomplicated.

Comment: Thanks mate. You strongly advise against it. Is it for readability?

Comment: @amars - Readability, debugability, maintainability, and if it's in a performance-critical part, performance -- too many temporary allocations, too many hidden loops. :-)